# Create TCP to HTTP Tunnel

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, tcp

I have setup my `node.js` application on `AWS EC2 linux` machine and my application is running on `TCP` connection.

Now, I have to move it and redirect traffic to HTTP.

Could any one suggest me the steps do it by program? Is it possible to create tunnel for `TCP` to `HTTP` ?

Thanks

Comment: Please describe the end problem you're really trying to solve rather than just the technical solution you are exploring.  With the right context, folks here may be able to point you to an already built solution.

Comment: The question is not really clear to me. How can you redirect TCP traffic to HTTP when HTTP is a protocol OVER TCP?

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting. i got solution for it.i have used "node-http-tunnel".